# Boolean is not Serializable?

Tags: scala, serializable

Consider this tiny snippet:

```
scala> val u = true.asInstanceOf[Serializable]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to scala.Serializable
```

Well that is a bit of a surprise..  The motivation is to support a modest range of classes - both primitives and custom classes (which *do* explicitly `extends Serializable).

So then what is the way to handle automatic serialization of these primitives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*java.lang.Boolean* is not *scala.Serializable*. It is however *java.io.Serializable*:

```
scala> val u = true.asInstanceOf[java.io.Serializable]
u: java.io.Serializable = true
```

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Serializable for information about *scala.Serializable* which seem to indicate some kind of cross platform serialization between JVM and .NET.

Comment: Sounds like a useful insight. I am looking into it now.

Comment: Apparently I will need to pay more attention to *which* Serializable intellij offers to import for me. The scala version is rarely (if ever) the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` to serialize/deserialize objects:

```
import java.io.{ObjectOutputStream, FileOutputStream, ObjectInputStream, FileInputStream}

object Test extends App {

    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("bool.obj"))
    oos.writeObject(true)
    oos.close()

    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("bool.obj"))
    val obj = ois.readObject()
    println(obj) // Prints: true
    ois.close()

}
```

Those stream classes are part of Java (not Scala) binary serialization framework. Consequently it's enough for class to extend `java.io.Serializable` to be serializable. `boolean` primitive is considered to be `java.io.Serializable`:

```
true.isInstanceOf[scala.Serializable] // false
true.isInstanceOf[java.io.Serializable] // true
```

Comment: Yes I did not notice it were scala.Serializable instead of java.io.Serializable.